# What metrics should I use when developing the first model?

Tags: predictive-models, model-evaluation, metric

When I build the first regression model for a new project, standard metrics such as MSE, MAE, R2 score can't tell if the first model will work well in production because there are no existing models to compare with using these metrics. Is there any special metric/way other than expensive experimentation which can give me some ideas about the performance of the first model?

Comment: Did you use cross validation?

Comment: @RobertLong I’m curious where you’re going with that. I take this question to be more like “I estimate the MSE t be 4 (or 3-5)...how do I know if this is useful to my company?”